# plugin incompatible with the new build found .ignore

Tags: android-studio, gitignore

I get an update on Android Studio Version 3.3 but there is a message saying :

### plugin incompatible with the new build found .ignore.

what should I do?
if I update whether the .ignore plugin really doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the *exact* error message is:

```
Plugin Error
Problems found loading plugins:
The following plugins are incompatible with the current IDE build: .ignore
```

That was reported in [`hsz/idea-gitignore` issue 408](https://github.com/hsz/idea-gitignore/issues/408) and then [issue 491](https://github.com/hsz/idea-gitignore/issues/491)

[Android Studio 3.3](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/android-studio-33.html) includes  Intellij 2018.2.2

Make sure that plugin is updated to its latest version first (3.0.0).
If not working, try and downgrade to 2.6.x, to test if a past version is compatible.

Comment: oh, okay thank you for your response and answer, friend. I was really scared when I finished updating Android version 3.3 what will happen later.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your Android Studio 3.3 again. When I update it today, it prompted an message to notify me to update the .ignore plugin to v2.6.2. After I update the plugin and restart Android Studio, it works well.

Comment: yes actually automatic handling appears from IDE :v

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same error like

```
Plugin Error: Plugin ".ignore" is incompatible (target build range is 192 to 193).
```

**How to resolve and below steps to follow in Android Studio**

1. Go to **File** Menu -> Settings -> Plugins -> Search **.ignore** Plugins
2. Update the **.ignore** Plugins and once updated then **Restart the IDE**

Answer (score 0):

Close Android Studio And Restart it and it works for me. Don't Invalid Cache & restart it doesn't reflect for this type of Issue.